# Tensorflow: Graph of the iterator is different from the graph the dataset was created in

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, keras-tuner

While using the Keras_tuner library I got the error in the title. I have no clue how to fix it and could not find any solutions for some time.

I am using Tensorflow BatchDatasets and passing them for the Hyperparameter tuning.

```
batch_size = 5
train_data = keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    x_train_scaled,
    y_train_scaled,
    1,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=False
)

val_data = keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    x_val_scaled,
    y_val_scaled,
    1,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=False
)

test_data = keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    x_test_scaled,
    y_test_scaled,
    1,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=False
)

# design network
def build_model(hp):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(hp.Choice('units', [8, 16]), activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])))
    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(hp.Choice('units', [8, 16]), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(hp.Choice('units', [8, 16]), activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
    return model

tuner  = keras_tuner.RandomSearch(
    build_model,
    objective='val_loss',
    max_trials=100)

tuner.search(train_data, epochs=100, shuffle=False, validation_data=val_data)
best_model = tuner.get_best_models()[0]
```

The problem is not with the input shapes or anything, as the same model works if I wasn't using the keras tuner.
The full error is:
`ValueError: The graph  of the iterator is different from the graph  the dataset: Tensor("PrefetchDataset:0", shape=(), dtype=variant) was created in. If you are using the Estimator API, make sure that no part of the dataset returned by the "input_fn" function is defined outside the "input_fn" function. Otherwise, make sure that the dataset is created in the same graph as the iterator.`

And the Line that triggers it is:
`tuner.search(train_data, epochs=100, shuffle=False, validation_data=val_data)`

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to fix the Problem in this case.
Instead of using the BatchDataset's I have swapped to use np.array's.
Also I have added `overwrite = True` for the `keras_tuner.RandomSearch`
The code now runs, however I still have no clue what that error was about.

```
# design network
def build_model(hp):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(hp.Choice('units', [8, 16]), activation='relu',return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])))
    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(hp.Choice('units', [8, 16]), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(hp.Choice('units', [8, 16]), activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
    return model

tuner  = keras_tuner.RandomSearch(
    build_model,
    objective='val_loss',
    overwrite=True,
    max_trials=100)

tuner.search(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, shuffle=False, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
best_model = tuner.get_best_models()[0]
```